# How to set the dynamic search parameter correctly in the url?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, url, search, fetch

**Am I setting the dynamic search parameter correctly in the url? Or I should use the backticks or other syntacsis? I need to search by the input the objects inside a backend url endpoint.

https://codesandbox.io/s/onscroll-izfjoc?file=/index.html**

```js
people: [],
getAllProducts(searchInput) {
  let searchUrl = searchInput;
  fetch(`http://test.mosvesna.com/?search=${searchUrl}`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((res) => {
        let local = this;
        if (searchInput) {
          this.people = res.filter((i) => i.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchInput.toLowerCase()));
        } else {
          this.people = res;
        }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to use backticks to be able to use [string interpolation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#string_interpolation)

But the code you posted doesn't make much sense in a real world scenario.
If you're sending a search parameter to the API then one would expect you're going to get filtered data.
That means you don't have to filter it yourself.

Also, you're assigning a lot of variables which you don't use later on. What's the purpose of `searchUrl` and `local` variables?

Comment: searchInput stands for the input.target.value and local is for getting the "this" outside the scope

Comment: Does it mean that in a real world scenario I would need to delit the if statement inside the function ? How would the function look like interesting ?

Comment: @AlexanderFilippovich that means that in a real world scenario you wouldn't have the if statement at all. You would just use the data the API sent you. Of course, there are lots of projects with bad management/team leads so even in real world projects this scenario could happen but it's not ideal for a frontend dev